# How to check array is not NULL using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have this array:

```
var someArr = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

At some point I need to check that array is not null or length of the array > 0.

What is elegant way to implement it in Angularjs?

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to do. At what point do you need it?

Comment: There is no specific stuff to check array is null in angular, you have to check `.length` of an array whether it's `someArr` or `$scope.someArr`!

Comment: AngularJS is JavaScript framework, So you can check length > 0 in if-condition `if(someArr.length > 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just check if the variable (array,object anything) has a truthy value or not. That means :

```
if( value ) {
}
```

will evaluate to true if value is not:

```
 1. null
 2. undefined
 3. NaN
 4. empty string ("")
 5. 0
 6. false
```

This is for above six conditions. But in case you have array define as:

```
 var arr = [];
```

then you need to check `arr.length`

Comment: This also means you're willing to assume you're testing an array.

Answer (score 1):

This question is more related to JavaScript, not AngularJS.

```
function nonEmpty(arr) {
    return !!arr && arr.length > 0;
}
```

Examples:

```
nonEmpty(['a'])      // true
nonEmpty([])         // false
nonEmpty(null)       // false
nonEmpty(undefined)  // false
```

Comment: The `> 0` is not necessary to check the emptiness of an array

Comment: You are right, it is not necessary, *but* I like it this way, because it *shows the intent* behind the condition and this way the function will *return a boolean* value, not `null`s `undefined`s `number`s or anything you supply to it. If you are fine with functions just returning random typed values it could be simply `return arr && arr.length`

Comment: The examples would be `1 0 false false` with your suggestions, or `1 0 null undefined` with the latter, not only booleans.

Answer (score 1):

I guessing you mean something like the following:

```
angular.isDefined()
```

Which is archievable by defining it yourself at the root of your application

```
angular.isNotNullOrZero = function(array) {
    return !!array && !!array.length;
}
```

So you can use it throughout your application.

```
var someArr = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(angular.isNotNullOrZero(someArr);
```

etc..

But like others said, this is just plain JS.